# "QSQLITE driver not loaded" Qsqldatabase error

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I am facing an issue with QSqlDatabase.
I get an error saying, "QSqlite driver not loaded".
To analyze it we have implemented a sample test code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtSql/QtSql>
using namespace std;
#define FC_BT_DB_CONNECTION_NAME "fc_bluetooth_database_connection"

int main() {
   QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", FC_BT_DB_CONNECTION_NAME );

      if (db.isValid())
                  cout<<"db is valid";
          else
                cout<<"ERROR db is NOT valid";
          return 0;
    }
```

Listing 1. Test Code

On running the above code:

```
bash-3.2# ./sqltest
QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers:
QSqlDatabase: an instance of QCoreApplication is required for loading driver plugins
ERROR db is NOT valid
```

Listing 2. The error displayed on the console

The setup used in Eclipse to build the test code is listed below.

[image]
  Fig 1. The Build Variables set in Eclipse

[image]
  Fig 2. The includes 
[image]
 Fig 3. The linker libraries

Anybody have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you read the error message that mentions `QCoreApplication`?

Comment: CL is quite right. There must be an instance of QCoreApplication running somewhere. Even if it's only an instance.